# Find the value of $c$ such that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{nc} = 10$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Find the value of $c$ such that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} e^{nc} = 10$$

I don't even know how to start this.

This is a geometric series so inorder for it to converge to any number it has to be $|e^{nc}| < 1$

my attempt:

$$|e^{nc}| < 1$$

$$|nc| < \ln 1$$

Comment: sum up the geometric series (only possible for $c<0$ which is your first restriction) and see where it takes you

Comment: $\frac{e^c}{1-e^{c}} = 10$, $$11e^c = 10 \leftrightarrow c = ln(\frac{10}{11})$$

Comment: For completeness, note that the conditions $$|e^{nc}| < 1$$ and $$|nc| < \ln 1$$ are not related. The former is equivalent to $$e^{nc}<1$$ which is equivalent to $$nc<0$$ while the latter never holds since $\ln1=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the geometric series formula, that sum is $\frac{e^{c}}{1-e^c}$. Notice that the series only converges for $c<0$, so our answer is only valid if it gives that $c$ is less than $0$. Setting this equal to $10$ and doing a bit of algebra gives us $10e^c+e^c=10\Rightarrow e^c=\frac{10}{11}$. Thus the answer is $c=\ln(10)-\ln(11)<0$

Comment: It would be good to specify the sum is the one you wrote only when $c<0$; however, +1

Comment: @Joe How's that?

Comment: @StellaBiderman NICE :-)